# Spring Boot Spring Data - @ID

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

By default spring data does not expose @Id field in response. But my return object contains @ID value.

I have looked up online most questions are how to expose the ID field.

I can create new POJO, iterate through return objects and set only the values I need. But I'm wondering why the default behavior is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to manage entity's property and make them appear or hide in the response, then you better have to use Jackson's framework annotations. `@JsonProperty("responseName")` will forse a property to appear in the response with a given name, `@JsonIgnore` will make a property do not appear in the response. 
Hope it'll help.